# Raspberry Pi, Python: How to send large data over usb serial?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am trying to send a large amount of data from my Raspberry Pi 4 to my computer. I configured the Raspberry Pi as USB OTG Serial Gadget and the data is sent through the usb-c port to my computer.

Please take a look at the following code running on the Raspberry Pi. One MB of data is sent.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial( port='/dev/ttyGS0', baudrate=115200)

packet = bytearray()
for i in range(0, 1000000):
    packet.append(0x2f)

ser.write(packet)
```

This is the code I am running first on my computer.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM30', baudrate=115200)

sum = 0
while 1:
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    if bytesToRead > 0:
        serial_line = ser.read(bytesToRead)
        sum += bytesToRead
        print(sum)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

I would expect that the received data has always the same length as the sent data. But in this example the computer receives a data length of around 990.000 Bytes in most cases. Even if I run the code without the sleep function on my computer, there are sometimes missing bytes.

How can I make sure that the data is sent and received without data loss?

Comment: The `sleep()` will certainly interfere with receiving data. Perhaps try: `else: time.sleep(0.001)`. Also remove `print(sum)` as this might be another pause.

Comment: There is still data loss. I am wondering if this is a Raspberry issue or the problem always exists when using usb serial.

Comment: Try lower baud rates and smaller packet sizes to find the limits. Otherwise you are going to need some sort of packet splitting.

Comment: I got the same results with baud rate 9600. I splitted the package into chunks of 1 Kb and it seems that this solves the problem. Unfortuanately this makes the data transfer extrem slow.

Comment: Your transfer has no flow control, i.e. if your reader is not as fast as your writer, then the reader will have buffer overrun, hence the loss of data.  USB has no handshake lines like RS232.  You need to use a XON-XOFF style of flow control or a request-response message protocol to meter the data to prevent receive buffer overrun.  BTW comparing the number of bytes sent versus count read is a low-quality method of checking data integrity.

Comment: You're right. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=283154

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have enabled logins on the serial port, you need to disable them first otherwise the port will be inaccessible.

Second, stop `getty@ttyGS0.service` and disable it.

And then everything will work fine.